# Compare file values across lines

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file with the following contents, depicting ranges.

```
27,16634
16634,228884
228884,263485
263485,570159
570159,574578
574578,582558
582558,589176
589176,610406
610406,758369
758369,761788
761788,1204053
1204053,2709997
2709997,2881177
2881177,2885709
2885709,2892004
2892004,2899595
2899595,2907546
2907546,2918485
2918485,2998518
2998518,3052950
3052950,3058420
3058420,3064901
3064901,3069132
3069132,3073363
3073363,3077670
3077670,3082448
3082448,3090852
3090852,3227270
3227270,5847341
5847341,7748374
```

I need to validate that:

1. On the same line, the line's left value <= line's right value
2. On consecutive lines, the above line's right value <= bottom line's left value

Comment: What's expected output?

Comment: Just a true/false?

Comment: @rs79 Did we help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk -F, '$1>$2 || (NR>1 && p>$1){exit 1} {p=$2}' file && echo "true" || echo "false"
```

Here we store 2nd column of previous line in a variable `p`.

Comment: Note that this does not properly handle the case in which the first entry in the file is negative.

Answer (score 0):

When we assume each line has two fields with a comma, you want to see that all numbers are equal to or larger than the last one.
In this special case you can check all fields with

```
[[ $(tr "," "\n" < file) == $(tr "," "\n" < file |sort -n) ]] && echo "true" || echo "false"
```

With the `sort -c` option this is easier:

```
tr "," "\n" < file | sort -nc 2>/dev/null && echo "true" || echo "false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Walter's solution -

```
$: tr , "\n" < file | sort -n --check && echo valid    
valid
```

The `tr` converts all commas to newlines, rendering the file into a single column which your OP says ought to be in numerically sorted order.

`sort -n --check` returns a valid zero return code if they are in numerically sorted order, or a 1 if they are not.

The `echo` is just reporting - the `&&` checks `sort`'s return and tells you if the file is good.